# Google analytics for apps real time is laggish

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics

the real time report is very laggish like 3-5 minutes after real action in app I show it in the real time interface.
the real time report for website is 'real' real time like 3-5 sec
so I want to know if this a bug in the plugin or this is how google analytics for mobile is working?

I am using cordova and this plugin: 
https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

Comment: Is the GA SDK sending the events in batches? Does decreasing the ga_dispatchPeriod help?

Comment: I looked at the code they using setLocalDispatchPeriod(30), any way the real time should work normal or its ok this 5 minutes lag?